# Plotting a buffer polygon over wrld_simpl

Tags: raster, terra

I want to create a buffer around a set of spatial points and plot it over wrld_simpl, without using ggplot2. Yet, there seem to be some issues with the projection I do not quite understand.

here is my reproducible example:

```
lat= c(31.19, 30.85)
lon= c(34.60, 34.79)
locs=data.frame(lon,lat )
coordinates(locs)=~lon+lat
 b=rgeos::gBuffer(locs, width = 250000)
 b=spTransform(b,projection(wrld_simpl))
 plot(wrld_simpl)  
 plot(b,col="red",add=T)# all red, why?
```

Comment: 2.5M degrees is a long way..

Comment: of course! thanks if you offer that as answer i will accept it

Comment: Don't use the "rstudio" tag for R questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with `terra`:

```
library(terra)
w <- geodata::world(path=".")

lat <- c(31.19, 30.85)
lon <- c(34.60, 34.79)
locs <- vect(cbind(lon,lat ), crs="+proj=longlat")
b <- buffer(locs, 250000)

plot(w)  
plot(b, border="red", add=T)
```